# Subset of html tags in xml

Tags: html, xml, tags, xsd

I am new to xml and html and i have a question :)

In the following xml:

```
<element name="itemDescription"> 
    <any minOccurs="0"/>            
</element>
```

How can the "itemDescription" tag be able to support a subset of HTML that uses only ul, li, b, i and span tags? 
Currently it is defined to accept any XML.

I have googled a lot on this one - but i cant come up with a solution. Only that i maybe could use complexTypes.

Can someone help me? :)

thx

Comment: Define "support". At which point would that support be checked how? Do you have an editor where this is being edited? An import process where you need to validate it?

Comment: I dont know - but is supposed to be restricted to use only a part of the html tags(the ones described)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that HTML very little to do with XML except a similar syntax.

You could look at the [schema of XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/) and copy out the parts you need, but it would be probably be easier to implement them yourself.

In any case IMHO it's not a good idea to try to re-implement (X)HTML inside a XML application. It would probably be easier to either

- implement something similar to HTML and have the application reading your XML convert it to HTML
- store your HTML as a (CDATA) string instead
- don't use HTML but for example a [lightweight markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow a specific set of XHTML elements as children of itemDescription, what you need to do is specify which children those are by defining an appropriate complex type.  (If your schema is intended to be XSD, then you'll also want to correct the syntax errors in your existing element declaration.)  From the specific XHTML elements you mention, I guess you also want idemDescription to be allowed to contain character data.

A declaration of itemDescription that does the job would look something like this:

```
<xsd:element name="itemDescription">
  <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element ref="xhtml:ul"/>
      <xsd:element ref="xhtml:b"/>
      <xsd:element ref="xhtml:i"/>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Since you need to refer to specific items in the XHTML namespace, you will need to import it, as well.  The simplest way to do so is with an import that looks like this:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

But at some point you will need to direct your XSD validator to a schema document for XHTML; some people prefer to do that on the import statement and not at invocation time, so they specify a schemaLocation attribute on the import statement:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
            schemaLocation="..."/>
```

Here the "..." will need to be replaced by a pointer to the XHTML schema you want to use.  (A local copy is recommended, since [W3C makes it excruciatingly slow to retrieve schema documents from their site](http://www.w3.org/Help/Webmaster.html#slowdtd) as a way of trying to discourage excessive DTD and schema traffic.)

Since you say you're new to XML, it may be helpful to have a complete schema document with everything in one place.  Again, remember to replace the schemaLocation value with a URI, if you want to use this in practice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
              schemaLocation="..."/>

  <xsd:element name="itemDescription">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="xhtml:ul"/>
        <xsd:element ref="xhtml:b"/>
        <xsd:element ref="xhtml:i"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```